# Finding tf-idf value in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I want to know how can we compute tf-idf value of words in R if my text is stored in vector.Till now I have scrape a news website using rvest Package and extracted the link and from there, articles and saved those article in a vector.

Now, my vector contains article in character format,Help me to find tf-idf value from there.Thanks in advance.Here is the code

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
pagetitle <- read_html("http://indianexpress.com/latest-news/")
pagetitle
url <- pagetitle%>%html_nodes(".title a")%>%html_attr("href")
len <- length(url)
articles <- c()
cnt <- 1
for (i in 1:2)
{
 #url
 h_text=""
 c_text=""
 newpage <- read_html(url[i])
 heading <- newpage%>%html_nodes("h1")%>%html_text()
 content <- newpage%>%html_nodes("p")%>%html_text()
 heading <- sapply(heading,tolower)
 heading <- gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',heading)
 heading <- gsub('[0-9]+','',heading)
 h_text  <- paste(h_text,heading,sep = " ")
 content <- sapply(content,tolower)
 n <- length(content)
 for(i in 1:n)
 {
   content[i] <- gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',content[i])
   content[i] <- gsub('[0-9]+','',content[i])
   c_text <- paste(c_text,content[i],sep = " ")
 }
#h_text
articles[cnt] <- c_text
cnt <- cnt+1
rm(heading,content,h_text,c_text,n,len)
}
articles[1]
articles[2]
```

Comment: can you share some code first?

Comment: Have a look at [Tidy Text Mining](http://tidytextmining.com/); Chapter 3 explains one way to calculate tf-idf in R.

Comment: Thanks for useful resource @ChristophWolk..